# Worksheet Change add Now() without Automatically updating

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am very new to VBA but I was hoping someone can help. I am trying to create a timestamp using the code below. But I can't figure out how to copy it for the next row.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 2 Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then
      Cells(2, 4).Value = ""
    Else
      Cells(2, 4).Value = Format(Now, "H:mm:ss AM/PM")
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

It works fine for that 1 cell. But how can I repeat this when I enter something in A3,A4..so on. This is probably a very basic question but I am a total newbie!

Comment: Do you always want `D2` to add time?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the check for row 2 and use Target.Row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 1  Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then
      Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = ""
    Else
      Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = Format(Now, "H:mm:ss AM/PM")
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool posted same time, at list not the same :-)

Comment: can I use this on a protected sheet?

Comment: Will probably have to unprotect and then protect. Can be done with code. Simple: `Unprotect` ... `Protect`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it,

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A99999")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Cells(2, 4).Value = ""
        Else
            Cells(2, 4).Value = Format(Now, "H:mm:ss AM/PM")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Or else you wanna add on every offset cell

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A99999")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = ""
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 3) = Format(Now, "H:mm:ss AM/PM")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

*[Worksheet.Change Event (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)*

*[Range.Offset Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx)*

Comment: wow thanks for the quick response! Would this work on a protected sheet?

Comment: @DANNYJ1 is it protected with the password?

Answer (score 0):

just to throw in a one-liner:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = IIf(Target.Value = "", "", Format(Now, "H:mm:ss AM/PM"))
End Sub
```

NOTE:

with `_Change` events you normally want to add code lines that set `Application.EnableEvents` to `False` before code lines that *change* something (cells content in this case) and to then back to `True` once you're done with the *changes*. This, not to have the event handle trigger itself in a infinite loop

In this case such an `Application.EnableEvents` handling isn't necessary because your are changing cells in column 4 and the `_Change` event handler would effectively do something only for changes in column 1